# Cheap way to get a clear plastic coffee table? For lying underneath it and using a windows 8.1 tablet on top

Tags: home, technology, plastics, furniture, office

**I put this in lifehack stack exchange because I think also an alternative to the below could be built out of easy household obnjects that I just not have thought of

I'm going to use a windows 8.1 or windows 10 tablet lying down on my back on the floor with a wireless mouse. A tablet will be maybe 1-2 feet from my eyes suspended above my face face down on top of a clear plastic table surface. This is how:

I'm going to lie down underneath a clear object shaped like the object in the following amazon link. I'll put the little table on my bed or on the floor. I'll face upward, the tablet will face downward:

Ideally the legs of the table would be stick shaped/cylinder shaped as opposed so what they are below so my hands can be more free.

[http://www.amazon.com/Acrylic-Table-premium-domestic-material/dp/B00J30U7P6/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1453487678&sr=8-2&keywords=clear+table](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J30U7P6)

The tablet will be

> **Could you help me kick around some ideas to deal with these issues?**
>
> 1. Searching amazon shows alot of coffee tables made out of glass or acrylic. I'm looking for something lighter like clear plastic so I can easily move the little table from my bed to the floor. I'm not very strong. 
>      http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=clear+coffee+table&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aclear+coffee+table
> 2. I'd really prefer some kind of clear plastic rather than glass because if it breaks, then I don't want to deal with those dangerous glass shards.
> 3. There must be a way cheaper way than to buy what I"m looking for. Alot of the clear amazon coffee tables are way overpriced for what they are like 200, 300 dollars.
> 4. I'd really prefer not to have to build it. But it is a possibility. I don't know how to build anything. However, I am on a college campus engineering school so there are machines and tools in various labs. I don't know what I'd look for. A bandsaw? Some kind clear plastic material? And then ask for permission to use the lab tools though when I worked in a chemistry lab, I had to get a position in the lab by application and do safety/regulation training just get in.

Comment: Use a windows 10 tablet on it.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about Lifehacks. Purchasing something frugally does not count as a Lifehack.

Comment: Yes let me add also that- it seems possible that what I want to accomplish could be made out of household objects as well. Do you have any ideas? And yes I will upgrade to windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like this instead.
[image: tablet holder]

1. Most are fairly light, or have wheels for easy moving.
2. It's not glass, so you won't have to worry about glass shards.
3. Most I've seen cost under 100$. Can be as low as 20-30$.
4. Minimal building is required. At most putting a few parts together.
5. Fulfills the same role you want the table to fulfill.
6. Takes up less room than a table.

Comment: What are they called? What did you google to find something like that? I've been googling tablet mount or tablet holder and have tend to find clamp on desk style tablet mounts but not something like your picture. Also I will probably use my thinkpad yoga which is significantly heavier than most tablets

Comment: @LongApple i think i googled tablet stand for bed. Flexible floor tablet stand also produces similar results. I got the picture from here http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/252243357193?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82

Answer (score 0):

Goodwill and other "second hand" stores may have something similar for a good price.

Additionally (and this may sound odd), drive around the neighborhoods near your college where the students live. College students often put furniture out on the sidewalks when they're done with it! Someone may have discarded a plastic coffee table that is just what you're looking for. It may need minor repairs, so be prepared for that. (I found an acoustic guitar with a broken neck this way. I just fixed the neck with a wood screw and played it for years.)